# ERROR on SIM900AT comand HTTPDATA (POST method)

Tags: gsm, datalogging, http, tcpip

Good day community, I have a project which is VEHICLE GPS Tracker and I'm using Arduino Mega, NEO GPS6MV2 and SIM900. I'm using SIM900 to send the GPS coordinates on a web server. I'm using the POST method and SIM900 is capable of this by using AT commands. I will also save the coordinates on a MySQL database.
My problem here is I can't send the data on the MySQL database. As you can see on the latter part of the commands, it response "ERROR". [image] That's why the coordinates failed to enter on the database. This is what I have on the database: [image]What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: Is there a 10 second delay between `DOWNLOAD` and `ERROR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you say you are going to send 90 characters you **must** send 90 characters. No more, no less. I count 70 there.
2. You have to send them immediately the modem responds `DOWNLOAD` otherwise it times out (10 seconds) and you get `ERROR`. It looks to me like you're not sending anything (except maybe a blank line) for those 10 seconds and only trying to send once it has errored.